# Spring Data Neo4j (SDN): Nested objects not populated by cypher

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am new to a graph database and the requirement is to migrate from neo4j 1.9.1 to the latest one. I have successfully configured it to use latest one but facing some difficulties in retrieving nested objects/collections.

In the existing implementation, the properties had `@Fetch` annotations but it's no more available.

When I query the database, it returns the correct amount of nodes but those nodes do not contain the nested object/relationships.

For instance, my POJO looks like this:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Category {

@GraphId
Long id;
private String categoryId;
@Index
private String unitId;

@Index
private String companyCategoryCode;
private String companyLabel;
private String supplierId;

@Relationship(type = "CHILD_OF", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
private Category parent;
... getters and setters
}
```

The repository looks like this:

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends GraphRepository<Category> {
  @Query(
  "MATCH (:ContentViewGroup {token:{token},active:true})-[:ASSOCIATED]-
  (:ContentView {active:true})-[r:MAPS_WITH]-(category:Category) "
      + "WHERE r.count > 0  "
      + "RETURN category ")
  List<Category> getCategories(@Param("token") String cvGroupToken);
}
```

I always get `null` in the `parent` object of `Category` class.

Any help in this regard?

NOTE: I am using Neo4j-ogm-api v2.1.6 and Spring data neo4j v4.2.10-RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the parent category within the cypher query as well.

For example:
`MATCH (:ContentViewGroup {token:{token},active:true})-[:ASSOCIATED]-(:ContentView {active:true})-[r:MAPS_WITH]-(category:Category)-[:CHILD_OF]->(parent:Category) WHERE r.count > 0 RETURN category, parent`

SDN/OGM can only create objects for data they receive from Neo4j.

Comment: thanks for your reply. That really helped but I still get the parent object as null in the returned category object. I then created a new class annotated as QueryResult and got a separate object parent in it. Is it the right way to do that?